# Removing main menu on large map page

Tags: navigation, menu, fullscreen, maps

I have a small map on my page, and want to allow the user to look at a larger version of it if a link is clicked.

On this new page, the map will essentially be full screen, covering everything except for a little "back button" in the top left.

Is this OK? Or would it be preferable to maintain my main menu, and make the map as large as I can, keeping the main menu visible.

I guess this boils down to the fact that if the user clicks on the "view large map", the only way they can carry on browsing the site is by clicking the back button.

Answer (score 1):

Name your button or link not "view large map" but "full screen". Well-known and usual way to exit full-screen is to press ESC or click anywhere on full-screen image.

Answer (score 0):

If the large map is something separate to the normal user flow (similar to print preview) then have the link for view large map open in a separate window/tab.

The other way to do it is to design the 'back' button as a close link, same as if you've clicked on a thumbnail that brings up a big image.